# ssrs 2008 - cant access reportsmanager with "browser" user

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have set up my reportsmanager page with two accounts to have access using the "folder settings" security role assignment page. I added two accounts, lets call them "user" and "reportuser". "user" is a content manager role. "reportuser" is a browser role.

Likewise under "Site settings" I set up my "user" as the system administrator and the "reportsuser" as system user.

When I launch the reportsmanager page locally while logged in as "user" then I can access the site correctly as I expect.

When I try to access reportsmanager while logged in as "reportsuser" then it tells me RSAccessDenied. "user" is a member of Administrators. "reportsuser" is a normal user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though my "reportsuser" was set up as a site browser and a site settings config of system user I had to still launch IE as administrator (or completely disable UAC) to get my reportsuser able to view the page without an error. If I turned off UAC then this wasn't an issue but I have to leave UAC on. If you hit the reports manager page from XP it acts as normal. Stupid UAC.